# Bootstrap, scss, use some class name in scss code instead of writing it in html files

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

In Bootstrap 4 I can use `text-truncate` as a class in an element. Eg:

```
<span class="text-truncate">Any very long text</span>
```

What I need now is to use this class `text-truncate` in a scss file for many objects instead of writing it directly in .html files.

How to?

Can I use something like:

```
@import "text-truncate" from "bootstrap.scss";

.myBeautifulDiv {
  use text-truncate;
}
```

This would be great! Is it possible?

Comment: Use @extend... https://www.codeply.com/go/llhRs09GWa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can create placeholder classes in scss,

Placeholder classe names start with `%`.They, themselves, will not be included in the the output css files.

But they can be imported into other classes. Check example below.

**Just remember to load your bootstrap css first.**

```
 /*In bootstrap file*/
    .text-truncate{
      text-overflow:ellipsis;
      ...
      ...
    }
```

---

```
 /*In your scss file*/

%truncatedtext {  /*This is placeholder class*/
 @extend .text-truncate;  /*This will include/pull the actual bootstrap code*/
}

.class-a {
  @extend %truncatedtext;
  color: #000000;
}

.class-b {
  @extend %truncatedtext;
  color: red;
}
```

---

Its output will be

```
.text-truncate, .class-a, .class-b {
  /*trucate css code*/
}

.class-a {
  color: #000000;
}

.class-b {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible.  Go here (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/), click "Download Source", and what you're looking for is probably in the _scss folder.

Comment: Or preferably use a package manager like NPM